# Use of loc to update a dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updating, pandas-loc

I have a pandas dataframe (df) with the column structure :

```
month a b c d
```

this dataframe has data for say Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr. A,B,C,D are numeric columns. For the month of Feb , I want to recalculate column A and update it in the dataframe i.e. for month = Feb, A = B + C + D

Code I used :

```
 df[df['month']=='Feb']['A']=df[df['month']=='Feb']['B'] + df[df['month']=='Feb']['C'] + df[df['month']=='Feb']['D']
```

This ran without errors but did not change the values in column A for the month Feb. In the console, it gave a message that :

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>       Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I tried to use .loc but right now the dataframe I am working on, I had used `.reset_index()` on it and I am not sure how to set index and use .loc. I followed documentation but not clear. Could you please help me out here?
This is an example dataframe :

```
 import pandas as pd import numpy as np
 dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I want to update say one date : 2000-01-03. I am unable to give the snippet of my data as it is real time data.

Comment: could you attach a little example of your dataframe?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov : The dataframe I am working on is big, I tried to explain the logic here . I will see if I can create any dataframe

Comment: you could attach like part of your dataframe with  `df.head()` or `df.iloc[:10, :10]`

Comment: Why not just `df['a'] = df.b + df.c + df.d`?  You need to include sample data to clarify what you are trying to do and produce a MVE. [ask]

Comment: Anton and Alexander : This is an example dataframe : import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
I want to update say one date : 2000-01-03. I am unable to give the snippet of my data as it is real time data.

Comment: @UdayShankar for future, it's better to update your question with your data not in the comment

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you could see from the warning you should use `loc[row_index, col_index]`. When you subsetting your data you get index values. You just need to pass for `row_index` and then with comma `col_name`:

```py
df.loc[df['month'] == 'Feb', 'A'] = df.loc[df['month'] == 'Feb', 'B'] + df.loc[df['month'] == 'Feb', 'C'] + df.loc[df['month'] == 'Feb', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

While not being the most beautiful, the way I would achieve your goal (without explicitly iterating over the rows) is:

```
df.ix[df['month'] == 'Feb', 'a'] = df[df['month'] == 'Feb']['b'] + df[df['month'] == 'Feb']['c']
```

**Note**: `ix` [has been deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838999/pandas-replacement-for-ix) since Pandas v0.20.0 in favour of `iloc` / `loc`.