# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting this error when I try to use the .ix attribute of a pandas data frame to pull out a column, e.g. `df.ix[:, 'col_header']`.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

The script worked this morning, but this afternoon I ran it in a new Linux environment with a fresh install of Pandas. Has anybody else seen this error before? I've searched here and elsewhere but can't find it.

Comment: You were running an older version of pandas. See this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838999/pandas-replacement-for-ix

Answer (score 113):

try `df.iloc[:, integer]`

`.ix` is deprecated

By the way, `df.loc[:,'col_header']` is for str or Boolean indexing

Comment: I receive "Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types" for that.

Comment: "*By the way, df.loc[:,'col_header'] is for str indexing*" and will be required if the indexer was a Boolean mask.

Comment: *"`.ix` is deprecated"* - `.ix` was removed, not deprecated (which means discouraged but still available).

Answer (score 53):

Change .ix to .loc and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 28):

A fresh install today (Jan 30, 2020) would install `pd.__version__ == '1.0.0'`. With that comes a [removal of many deprecated features](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes).

> Removed Series.ix and DataFrame.ix (GH26438)

Answer (score 5):

Try following steps:
1) installing new version of Pandas
2) use .loc instead of .ix

Answer (score 4):

it works for me

**Use df.loc[] instade of ix[]**

Answer (score 2):

had same issue with pandas 1.0.0, this worked for me

Open Anaconda Prompt (cmd) as Administrator, then

conda install pandas==0.25.1

Your newer pandas version will be overwritten by older one!

Comment: No need to downgrade. Just use `.loc` for label indexing and `.iloc` for integer indexing

Answer (score 2):

I used .loc() instead of .ix() and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

as ix is removed

use iloc or loc inplace of ix.

use .loc if you have string or userdefined indexing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "as ix is removed" What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Ix is now not available to be used in pandas. You have to use .iloc Or loc these will give you same result.

Answer (score 1):

replace .ix with .iloc after replacing its works well for me also

predictions_ARIMA_log = pd.Series(ts_log.iloc[0], index=ts_log.index)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use `.ix[]`, you must downgrade your pandas version to 0.20.0. In newer versions, you could use `.loc[]` or `.iloc[]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

one column:

```
df[['sepal width']]
```

two columns:

```
df[['sepal width','petal width']]
```

special columns(select column include 'length'):

```
df[[c for c in df.columns if 'length' in c]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the book **'Python for data analysis'** by *Wes McKinney* and I met the same problem of Dataframe.ix[] while retrieving the rows with index.
I replace ix by iloc and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .ix as I have mixed indexing, labels and integers.  .loc() does not solve the issue as well as .iloc; both are ending in errors. I was intentionally using .ix because it was the fast lane when the index is a mix of integers and labels.

As example a df like:

[image]

My way out is to back-up columns and index, replace with integers, use .iat and then restore the df as it was at the beginning. I have something like:

```
# Save the df and replace indec and columns with integers
lista_colonne = list(df.columns)  
df.columns = range(0,len(lista_colonne))    
nome_indice = df.index.name
lista_indice = list(df.index)
df['Indice'] = range(0,len(lista_indice))
df.index = df['Indice']
del df['Indice']

  ... indexing here with .iat in place of .ix


# Now back as it was
df.columns = lista_colonne
df['Indice'] = lista_indice
df.index = df['Indice']
del df['Indice']
df.index.name = nome_indice
```

Bye, Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

```
returns.ix['2015-01-01':'2015-12-31'].std()
```

After much ado I made it happen using this:

```
returns.xs(key='2015',axis=0).std()
```

I believe at least for this case we can use cross section and filter using 2015 as key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's right. Replace `df.ix[]` with `df.iloc[]` or `df.loc[]`

Answer (score -2):

1. Guys try to update current pandas
2. replace .ix with .iloc
   after replacing its works well for me
   For details refers documentations