# What is an Attribute Error in site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to run these codes below.
Can someone explain what does this error mean to me?
I don't understand Attribute error and the pandas core generic coding section 
Is it some Pandas installation error?
Thanks for answering!

````
<ipython-input-5-c7aabb0a8819> in <module>
     13 
     14     # Plot first column of df
---> 15 pd.DataFrame.hist(df.ix[:, 0:1])
     16 plt.xlabel('fixed acidity (g(tartaric acid)/dm$^3$)')
     17 plt.ylabel('count')```

** These above are the codes that I tried to run
Then Jupyter notebook throw this error message out: **

> c:\users\...\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
> in __getattr__(self, name)
>          if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
>              return self[name]
> ->       return object.__getattribute__(self, name)    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None 
      AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
````

Comment: Take a look here, probably the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991397/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-ix

Comment: `.ix` is deprecated. Use `.loc` or `.at`