# pybacktest library hello world error: builtins.AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ix'

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, quantitative-finance, back-testing

Runnign the following [pybacktest](https://github.com/ematvey/pybacktest) code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pybacktest
import pandas as pd

short_ma = 50
long_ma = 200

ohlc = pybacktest.load_from_yahoo('AAPL', start=2000)
ohlc.tail()

ms = ohlc.C.rolling(short_ma).mean()
ml = ohlc.C.rolling(long_ma).mean()

buy = cover = (ms > ml) & (ms.shift() < ml.shift())  # ma cross up
sell = short = (ms < ml) & (ms.shift() > ml.shift())  # ma cross down

bt = pybacktest.Backtest(locals(), 'ma_cross')

print(bt.summary())

bt.plot_equity()
```

I get the error in the title, and for more info see this screenshot:

[image: pybacktest hello world error]

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: `.ix[]` is deprecated since pandas 0.20, you can either downgrade pandas or edit `pybacktest` source code by replacing `.ix[]` with `.loc[]`

Comment: @GustiAdli and you're 100% it shouldn't be replaced with `iloc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly with this thread:

[AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991397/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-ix)

I used the Call Stack of WingWare to back up to what was calling `__getattribute__`

and I replaced the line:

```
    eq = self.equity.ix[subset].cumsum()
```

(line 188 of backtest.py) with:

```
    eq = self.equity.loc[subset].cumsum()
```

Thanks to commenter @GustiAdli as well for confirming.

That code also was meant for a Jupyter notebook and the proper code should be:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pybacktest
import pandas as pd

short_ma = 50
long_ma = 200

ohlc = pybacktest.load_from_yahoo('AAPL', start=2000)
ohlc.tail()

ms = ohlc.C.rolling(short_ma).mean()
ml = ohlc.C.rolling(long_ma).mean()

buy = cover = (ms > ml) & (ms.shift() < ml.shift())  # ma cross up
sell = short = (ms < ml) & (ms.shift() > ml.shift())  # ma cross down

bt = pybacktest.Backtest(locals(), 'ma_cross')

print(bt.summary())

fig,ax = bt.plot_equity()
plt.show()
```

And the proper output should be:

[image: matplotlib output]

I am making a new repository for this change (and other fixes that need to be done):

https://github.com/enjoysmath/pybacktest

Since the original seems left alone (most recent issue message was from last year).